# Multiple lines or multiple matches in RewriteRules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Say I have a lot of rewriting to do:

- /apples
- /bananas
- /cherries

need to redirect to

- /fruit/apples
- /fruit/bananas
- /fruit/cherries

and so on, plus the same for a list of vegetables to /veg/vegetable-name, cakes to /cake/cake-name.

Would you do your redirects on one line each, or would you wrap them into one long rule:

```
/(apples|bananas|cherries)
```

to

```
/fruit/$1
```

are there performance issues with either approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single rule, only if:
1. I am confident of the options {apples, bananas, cherries} are limited
2. I am confident that the input will not exceed this limit of options OR that if it exceeds there is a good exception handling mechanism ( that is, what if the user sends a request for /papaya, which is not in the list)

If the list is frequently updated, or if the list is large, I would rather use a rewrite-map. This would also allow me to define a common exception handling using the default value for the map. Additionally, one map can suffice for all cases of fruits, vegetables, cars, etc.

From a performance perspective, the single rule with OR'd conditions will be more optimal than multiple rules with one condition.

The rewrite-map will be less optimal than the rewrite rules, but at some point I will start prioritizing readability and maintainability over performance.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't considered a RewriteMap. For the record this particular url type changes very rarely and new ones don't matter, they go straight to the /fruits/papaya directory—I'm just trying to retain the google juice from the old URLs.

Comment: if you are mapping `/apples -> /fruits/apples` and '/onions -> /vegetables/onions`; either you have to have an exhaustive list of fruits (or vegetables) to map or hope that the user does not attempt a new fruit (or vegetable).

Comment: It was just an example. The actual content is much less complex than a list of all possible fruits and vegetables!